# Fiction story about ice not floating, leading to the end of the world

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for the name of a story (or book) concerning scientists experimenting with ice in water. They devise a way to make ice sink, and it inevitably leads to the end of life as we know it.

Comment: The only "unusual ice ends the world" story I can think of is *Cat's Cradle* by Vonnegut.  It's not called "ice-nine" is it?

Comment: Probably dupe of this; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/180555/20774 - Sinking ice is a pretty rare trope

Comment: "*"I added a small amount of #$%&'. (Sorry, I can't translate this formula - C.) to some water, and placed the vessel in a cold chamber. Ice crystals soon formed, but although they were of the same appearance as ordinary ice, they sank to the bottom of the tube. ... I kept at it for days, but I was never able to dilute the solution sufficiently to make ice crystals that would float. The catalyst had imparted to the water the property of becoming more dense as it froze, and I was unable to change it back.*"

Answer (score 29):

The Story, *[Cat's Cradle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat%27s_Cradle)* by Kurt Vonnegut mentions ice-9, an alternative structure of water that is solid at room temperature. When a crystal of ice-nine contacts liquid water, it becomes a seed crystal that makes the molecules of liquid water arrange themselves into the solid form.

When a human body killed by contact with ice-9 comes into contact with the sea, all the water in the world's seas, rivers, and groundwater turns into ice-9.

Comment: That Vonnegut novel (Cat’s Cradle) sounds like the correct answer. Thanks for the help with an “ice-nine” question!

Comment: Strange thing, I would have sworn that Asimov started this trope, with a story simply titled "Ice 9".  I must have been drunk. :/

Comment: FWIW: The story violates deep laws of physics. Even if there was some crystalline form of water that was solid at room temperature, it would give off heat as it froze, and the heat that it gave off would warm the water, limiting the speed at which the freezing could propagate. The world's oceans freeze in a blink of an eye in the novel, but if Ice 9 was a real thing, it probably would take thousands of years (or maybe millions of years, I'm just guessing.)

Comment: @SolomonSlow When you have a supercooled solution it can flash to ice very quickly.  The ice-nine scenario basically makes the oceans into a supercooled solution.

Comment: @LorenPechtel, OK, Now that you mention it, I recall watching something like that happen when I uncapped a very cold bottle of pop. Took a few seconds though for the whole thing to freeze.  So maybe not thousands of years, but... Doesn't matter. I wouldn't want to discourage anybody from reading the novel. It's a great story.

Comment: "Ice IX" is indeed a real thing, but it only occurs below -133°C and at roughly 2000 times normal atmospheric pressure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_IX The only two states of water that appear in conditions that aren't already very deadly on their own are the regular solid and liquid forms: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/08/Phase_diagram_of_water.svg

Comment: @FabianRöling That just happens to share a similar name. Aside from being a form of ice, it has nothing in common with Ice-9 from the story.

Comment: @SolomonSlow thanks, that's comforting.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I believe that when the story was written the actual IX form wasn't known, although some other forms were known.  If it were to be written today it would probably be called something like Ice XX.

Comment: @FabianRöling Are you saying regular water and regular ice are not deadly on their own? Drowning victims and people who have broken their neck slipping on ice would beg to differ.

Comment: I'm saying the only conditions under which other states of water can occur are deadly on their own within a few seconds, not even needing the water. Like >90°C, <-100°C, <10% atmospheric pressure or >1000×atmospheric pressure. You **can** survive below 0°C for a while, but you can **not** survive at over 90°C for longer than a few seconds. Maaaybe you could survive for a short while at 15% atmospheric pressure and 50°C, long enough to observe water vapour around you and realise what's happening, but that's quite the stretch.

Answer (score 17):

Note that, per Valorum's comment above, a relatively obscure short story called "The Catalyst" by G. R. Yohe is a better match for the description than *Cat's Cradle*, and it was previously asked about and answered successfully [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/179359/trying-to-identify-short-story-about-the-second-ice-age).

As cited by Valorum, the story -- primarily conveyed in the form of the translation of a discovered alien journal -- does concern the creation (on an alien planet) of a substance that, when added to water, causes ice formed from that water to sink:

> "As everyone knows, even the youngest child in school, when water
>   freezes, the ice is lighter than the liquid, and floats on its
>   surface. But during !" (Note: a date, doubtless some years earlier -
>   Chemin.), I was experimenting with certain catalysts (catalyst may not
>   be the right word, but it means an additive of some sort - C.) to
>   modify crystal structure. I added a small amount of #$%&'. (Sorry, I
>   can't translate this formula - C.) to some water, and placed the
>   vessel in a cold chamber. Ice crystals soon formed, but although they
>   were of the same appearance as ordinary ice, they sank to the bottom
>   of the tube. This was odd and certainly had not been reported before,
>   so I investigated further, primarily to see how dilute a solution of
>   #$%&' would be effective in catalyzing the formation of this heavy ice..."

This effect continues even at vanishingly small levels of concentration of the mystery substance:

> "...I melted the crystals, pipeted out one tenth of the liquid and
>   diluted it with nine parts of fresh water. When this was cooled, the
>   ice crystals sank as before. I repeated, diluting to 1/100, 1/1000,
>   1/10,000 of the original concentration. Still the ice crystals sank. I
>   proceeded. One part in a million, one in a billion, one in a trillion.
>   I kept diluting until I lost track of the dilution; still the crystals
>   sank. I kept at it for days, but I was never able to dilute the
>   solution sufficiently to make ice crystals that would float. The
>   catalyst had imparted to the water the property of becoming more dense
>   as it froze, and I was unable to change it back..."

Per the story, this effect is not something being actively sought by the creator, but there is an attempt to commercialize the effect by some of the aliens, which may have influenced the OP's memory:

> "Oddly, the first public notice of the ominous events that were
>   transpiring came from an advertisement in our city newspaper. The
>   local ice company announced that it was placing on the market ice
>   cubes that would sink rather than float in water and that the
>   annoyance of ice striking the lips of drinkers of chilled beverages
>   was a thing of the past. This campaign to sell this oddity was short
>   lived, however, as people all over the city noted in surprise that
>   their own homemade ice cubes had the same property. Soon ice with
>   similar behavior was reported from other cities, not only in the
>   nearby river system, but in other watersheds. My catalyst was
>   spreading to the uttermost parts of the planet..."

Also note that, while these events transpired on an alien planet called Tsiai or Tsial (the spelling varies in the online version), contaminated samples are brought to Earth and accidentally injected into the environment:

> I looked at him, almost in panic at the thought that had just come to
>   me. "Never mind that now!" I cried. "Get me the foreman who was in
>   charge of the airport ground crew the day we landed. Immediately!"
>
> Chemin must have contacted the airport headquarters at once, for in
>   fifteen minutes, during which I could do nothing but pace the floor,
>   the foreman entered.
>
> "I'm the ground foreman," he said. "What can I do for you?"
>
> "The day we landed on our return from the space trip," I said, "a case
>   of bottled samples we dropped. How was that accident handled?"
>
> "Why, one bottle was broken. We swept up the glass and threw it away."
>
> "What happened to the contents?" I asked. "Well, it was raining, you
>   may remember," he answered. "Whatever was in the bottle was washed
>   away and down the drain, I guess."

In addition, an Earth company also tries to capitalize on the effect, which might further leave an impression of intentional creation:

> He took a newspaper from under his arm, opened it to the center page,
>   and handed it to me. "By the way," he said, "you're a chemist. What do
>   you think of this?" I read the advertisement he pointed out, but I
>   cannot describe the utter horror that I felt. "City Ice Company
>   announces a new product - ice cubes that sink in cold drinks!"

This story is not listed at ISFDB, but it is [available online via the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20160414005748/http://crcomp.net/SciFi/The%20Catalyst.html), and the footnote there indicates that it was originally published in an academic journal: "Reprinted from Chemistry Vol. 46, pp. 8-11 Sept. 1973"